# Continuous Integration, best practice to input actual test data into database, using Propel ORM

Tags: phpunit, continuous-integration, database-schema, propel

I used Propel ORM to duplicate a table schema, in order to do continuous integration, but Propel only gets me a fully fleshed out schema, it doesn't get me test data (or basic necessary data at all).

How do I get the data from a live/test database with a version controlled `propel-gen` Propel ORM ecosystem?

Comment: @halfer Yeah, I'd love to hear move around that, as I am happily using phpunit with codeship.io.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They say that "best practice" in anything at all doesn't exist - it's so subjective that one ought to settle for one of several forms of "good practice" instead. I *think* the below qualifies for that label — and ultimately it works well for me. I've been using PHPUnit for about a year, and perhaps for six months on my projects from scratch.

Here's a synopsis of what I do in the PHPUnit bootstrap phase (specified in `phpunit.xml`):

- Drop and create the `myproject_test` database
- Call the `insert-sql` Propel command on a pre-migrations copy of the generated SQL
- Call the `migrate` Propel command
- Scan my test folders for build classes to set up the tests, and run each in turn

The benefit of inserting SQL manually and then running migrations is that migrations get a really thorough testing. This is especially handy since in development I sometimes will do a `down`, modify a migration class, then do an `up` to re-run it: it is therefore reassuring to know it will run in order. At present I plan to keep all of my migration history permanently; whilst it will add very minor delay to testing and new builds, upgrade deployments won't be affected.

Since my build depends on having an old SQL file, I avoid using the `sql` generation command; if it is accidentally issued, the modified SQL files can be trivially reverted in version control.

At present, I am simply using a database name of `myproject_test` on `localhost`, so that wherever the tests are run, other database are not affected. It is possible that on build servers you will be required to connect using different credentials: consider detecting the machine name in a `switch()` statement, and selecting the connection details accordingly.

To give you data to test, I am generally inclined to recommend you don't use an export of data from your live system. There's usually too much of it, for one, and also you generally want to create pieces of data per test, so that tests are completely isolated. I think this is a good idea for two reasons:

- You can parallelise tests that are independent. So, when your browser test suite takes five hours to run (!) you can set up more build servers to get a green build more quickly.
- You may wish to locally run a test suite on its own, or a test on its own, or a set of tests matching a certain string, and this may not work if one test depends on another.

This is where my builder classes come in. I use this in my `bootstrap.php` and call it on each folder containing test classes:

```
function runBuilders($buildFolder, $namespace)
{
    // I use ! to mark common builders that need to be run first.
    // Since this confuses autoloader, I load that manually.
    $commonBuilder = $buildFolder . '/!CommonBuild.php';
    if (file_exists($commonBuilder))
    {
        require_once $commonBuilder;
    }

    foreach(glob($buildFolder . '/*Build.php') as $class)
    {
        $matches = array();
        $found = preg_match('#/([!a-zA-Z]+)\.php#', $class, $matches);
        if ($found)
        {
            echo '.';

            // Don't use ! characters when creating the class
            $className = str_replace('!', '', $matches[1]);
            call_user_func($namespace . "\\{$className}::build");
        }
    }
}
```

In `!CommonBuild.php` I add read-only data that won't be modified by tests, and so it is safe to have just one copy.

I have one build class per PHPUnit test class: for every `*Test.php` file I have, I will have a corresponding `*Build.php`. In each builder, a `build` static method is called, and in that I manually run a method for each test that needs something built. Here is a simple one:

```
public static function build()
{
    self::buildWriteVarToFieldSuccessfully();
    self::buildWriteVarToFieldUsingFailedMatch();
    self::buildWriteVarToFieldUsingFoundMatch();
    self::buildFailIfVariableIsAnArray();
}
```

At some point in the future I'll probably use Reflection to run these automatically, like PHPUnit does for tests, but it is fine for now.

Now, in my bootstrap script I fully initialise Propel, using the test connection, so ordinary Propel statements are available. I will thus create just the data I need, like so:

```
protected static function buildWriteVarToFieldUsingFoundMatch()
{
    // Save an item in the holding table
    $employer = self::createEmployer();
    $job = new \Job\Model\JobHolding();
    $job->setReference('12345');
    $job->setLocationAlias('Rhubarb patch');
    $job->setEmployerId($employer->getPrimaryKey());
    $job->save();

    $process = self::createProcessingUsingRowMatching($employer);
    $process->createSource('VarToFieldTest_buildWriteVarToFieldUsingFoundMatch');
}
```

I have a naming convention that a test of `testWriteVarToFieldUsingFoundMatch` in a test class gets a builder called `buildWriteVarToFieldUsingFoundMatch` in the corresponding build class. It's not enforced as such in code, but this naming helps find one given the other easily (I will often edit both at the same time, using my IDE's split screen feature).

So, in the example above, I only needed one employer record, one job record, one process record and one source record to run this particular test (and not a whole live export). The source record is given a unique name relating to the test name, so that it will only be used in this test (I've found I have to watch out for copy-and-paste errors here - it is quite easy to use the wrong data in a test!).

Creating test data of this kind is quite easy, whatever kind of database you have: `user.name` fields, `address.line1` fields and so forth can usually be created containing a unique identifier, so that when you modify this data in a test, you know that only that test is going to use it, and thus that it is isolated from other tests.

I've opted to run all builders in the bootstrap regardless of what tests are being run, for reasons of simplicity. Since this takes only 15 extra seconds, in my case it's probably not worth doing something more complicated. However, if you wish, you could do something clever with the `setUp` method in each PHPUnit test, detect the current test (if possible) and then run the appropriate build class.

Comment: Hmmm, I'll check this out and see if the process fits my needs, thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately, additionally a few days ago I was curious about the development status of propel and find that activity on the library seems to have tapered off, and it gradually seems to be turning into a unmaintained software library, which means I'm realistically probably going to have to completely rethink even my initial approach of using propel at all: https://github.com/propelorm/Propel/graphs/contributors

Comment: (This answer is getting a few more eyeballs as I have linked to it from a new, similar question. I should be most interested in any feedback from people as to whether they use this, or plan to having read it, or about drawbacks that I have not spotted).

Comment: Kzqai - I believe you are looking at the wrong version of the project - the latest is version 2: https://github.com/propelorm/Propel2/graphs/contributors

Comment: Yes, I did indeed eventually find that they have created a new Propel2 repo, and the version 1 propel repo currently doesn't mention the propel2 repo (yet?).

Comment: @Kzqai: Propel 2 is regarded as the current version, and the website points there. They say it is better unit-tested than version 1, but that it is still alpha and subject to BC breaks until it gets to beta.