# Doctrine 2 Migrations Workflow

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, data-migration

I am developing a web application using Zend Framework 2 and Doctrine 2. I'm new to Doctrine 2 in general and Migrations in particular. I was wondering if there are any recommended best practices in using this. Some specific things I'm looking for:

- A recommended workflow from development to deployment?
- Do you include pre-populating data in migrations?
- How to handle reverting to a previous version if migration fails.

Many thanks!

Comment: A few months ago I wrote [an answer for the Propel migrations workflow](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28671466/472495). I don't know how widespread my practice is (I made it up myself) - I build the unit test environment from migrations every time the tests are run. It makes for a much greater level of confidence before you run them in non-dev environments. It's not particularly Propel-specific, so maybe that is of interest?

Answer (score 4):

Doctrine has [own library for migrations](https://github.com/doctrine?utf8=%E2%9C%93&query=migration), that includes also Symfony bundle.

For Zend there probably is [some bundle as well](https://github.com/MurgaNikolay/DoctrineMigrationsModule) (maybe seek on Github a bit more)

As for your specific questions:

1. Nothing special. Basic workflow is nicely described in [Symfony bundle documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/DoctrineMigrationsBundle/index.html#usage). We use it in pretty same way even in a different framework.
2. Yes, so every developer has fully operational system. For tests we use data-fixtures with minimal required data only.
3. It's managed by this package itself.

Answer (score 1):

The Doctrine ORM module for ZF2 (DoctrineORMModule) has built-in support for Doctrine ORM migrations.  There's [a very brief blurb in the documentation about how to configure it](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineORMModule/blob/master/docs/migrations.md).  You can then access the migration commands (generate, migrate, etc) through the CLI interface that module provides (`vendor/bin/doctrine-module`)

As for my personal workflow I generally put initialization or pre-population data - the stuff you initially seed a new installation with - into database fixtures ([which Doctrine ORM also supports](https://github.com/doctrine/data-fixtures) and [there is a ZF2 module for](https://github.com/Hounddog/DoctrineDataFixtureModule)).

Comment: Do  I have tu explicitly require `doctrine/migrations` with composer, or just with `doctrine/doctrine-orm-module` is enough?